# Magic comment root document \jobname

Tags: jobname, root, magic-comment

I want to use `\jobname` as input for a magic comment `% !TeX root = \jobname.tex`, but it doesn't work. There are two files, one `*.tikz` and one `*.tex`.

MWE Tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\input{\jobname.tikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

MWE Tikz (with `\jobname`):

```
% !TeX root = \jobname.tex

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\jobname};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When compiling in `MWEJobname.tikz` it gives an error:

> Environment tikzpicture undefined. \begin{tikzpicture}

But when replacing `\jobname` in the `MWEJobname.tikz`with the actual file name `MWEJobname` it works:

```
% !TeX root = MWEJobname.tex

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\jobname};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I make it work using `\jobname` in the magic comment in the `tikz`-file, so that I don't have to manually put it in?

Comment: The magic comments aren’t read by TeX, but only possibly interpreted by the front-end.

Comment: And there is no other way to link these two tex-files "automatically" via their \jobname?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but this is *non sequitur*.

The purpose of that “magic comment” is to inform the *editor/front-end* about what file should TeX be run on when hitting the “typeset” button in the window showing the subfile.

The editor/front-end cannot know what `\jobname` should refer to, because `\jobname` is set when TeX is run. A “chicken and egg” problem.

Comment: Is there a possibility to let `WEJobname.tikz` read out its file name and parse it to the magic comment?